# Recorrer un array y suscribirse

Tags: angular, observable

Tengo un array de 3 elementos y un observable que me devuelve el valor de un contador el cual registro en la base de datos.

El caso es que necesito recorrer el array y obtener el valor correspondiente.
El problema es que siempre me devuelve el mismo valor.

Os pongo ejemplo:

```
   files.forEach((file: any, index) => {
      const filePath = (this.data) ? this.data : `Bloque1/`;
      this.counterControllerService.counterControllerGetNextCounterSequence(this.serialNumber)
      .subscribe((counter) => {
        file.nameCounter = `${this.serialNumber} - ${counter}`;
        this.s3Service.s3uploadimage(file, filePath).subscribe((s3File: S3File) => {
          this.file = s3File;
          this.file.fileName = `${this.serialNumber} - ${counter}`;
          imagenes.push(s3File)
          if (files.length === index + 1) {
            this.onUpload.emit(imagenes);
          }
        });
      })
    });
```

¿A alguien se le ocurre porque se sucede esto?

¡Gracias!

Comment: ¿Quieres decir que esta función devuelve siempre el mismo valor counterControllerService.counterControllerGetNextCounterSequence(this.serialNumber) ?

Comment: Si, siempre devuelve el mismo valor y no se incrementa dentro del array.

Comment: El problema no es del código que has añadido entonces sino del valor que devuelve el servicio counterControllerService. Deberías mirar si dentro del servicio devuelve distintos valores

Comment: La respuesta del servicio es un valor numérico, solo eso. No hay nada mas.
¿Puede ser porque al ya estar suscrito desde la misma función no vuelve a solicitar un nuevo valor?
He intentado hacer unsubscribe pero nada...

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de utilizar el subscribe utiliza promesas, te dejo un ejemplo de como sería con promesas a ver si no tienes el mismo problema.

```
await this.counterControllerService.counterControllerGetNextCounterSequence(this.serialNumber)
.toPromise()
.then(counter => {
    file.nameCounter = `${this.serialNumber} - ${counter}`;
    this.s3Service.s3uploadimage(file, filePath).subscribe((s3File: S3File) => {
      this.file = s3File;
      this.file.fileName = `${this.serialNumber} - ${counter}`;
      imagenes.push(s3File)
      if (files.length === index + 1) {
        this.onUpload.emit(imagenes);
      }
    });
})
.catch(err => {
    return Promise.reject(err);
});
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, pero me sigue pasando lo mismo...

Comment: Entonces si el valor counter es siempre el mismo es porque la llamada que haces al servicio no es correcta, para recibir distintas respuestas el parámetro de entrada debería variar. Prueba de ejecutar el back con Postman y veras si devuelve los resultados correctos

Comment: Te explico, este contador lo que hace es buscar por el serialNumber que le envío y si ya existe aumenta el contador.
El tema esta en que si añado un solo elemento al array, cada vez que lo llamo lo hace bien, pero cuando añado mas de uno, no....

Comment: Con lo que tengo no te puedo ayudar mucho mas, la parte de Front es correcta si el back no retorna los valores que debería es otro tema. Lo que dices que para un elemento funciona y para mas no yo lo probaría desde el Postman para asegurar que realmente devuelve lo que esperas porque tiene pinta que ahí esta el problema.

Comment: Gracias de todas formas!